# Web font: Some characters vertically squashed on Windows

Tags: css, windows, font-face

I'm experiencing a very weird problem with the web font I'm using on a project. Initially I thought this was an IE-only bug (showed up in IE 9 on Windows Vista, Windows 7). I was happy to revert to a system font for IE but now it's showing up in Chrome I'd really like to get to the bottom of the problem. Screenshot below:

[image: Font face Window bugf]

Edit: The font is [Aktiv Grotesk Light](https://www.daltonmaag.com/buyonline/fonts/aktivgrotesk), converted to a web font with the [Font Squirrel Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Answer (score 0):

OS X just has a better fontrendering thant Windows.
OS X uses `Subpixel rendering` witch makes the difference.

Are you using @fontface? Try cufón instead, in general fonts are better rendered with cufón than with @fontface on windows.

Comment: I'm using @fontface to render all the text on this particular site. Because of this Cufón isn't really an option.

Comment: I think the best option is to use another font that looks similar to Aktiv Grotesk Light

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in the font implementation, or in font rendering in Windows, depending on which side you take. Similar problems have been described in other questions, see e.g. [css google fonts cyrillic - some letters are cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246024/css-google-fonts-cyrillic-some-letters-are-cut-off/).

The practical solution might be to see if the font works better in a different size (1px can make a big difference), and if this does not help, to find another font.